# Как можно разбить список на вложенные списки, содержащие одинаковые идущие подряд элементы?

Tags: python, алгоритм, список

Как можно разбить список на вложенные списки, включающие в себя **одинаковые элементы, идущие подряд**?

Если **подряд идущих равных элементов нет**, необходимо создать вложенный список, содержащий **только этот один элемент**.

Что-то вроде:

Было: `array = [4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 9, 2]`

Стало: `array = [[4] [2, 2] [4] [5, 5, 5] [1] [6] [9, 9] [2]]`

Как можно реализовать подобное?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `itertools`. Конкретнее, функцией `groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

array = [4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 9, 2]

array = groupby(array) # получаем элемент groupby

new_array = []

for elem, grouper in array:
    new_array.append(list(grouper)) # если не проводить преобразование в какой-либо тип данных
                                    # получим itertools._grouper object at MemoryAdress in HEX

print(new_array) # [[4], [2, 2], [4], [5, 5, 5], [1], [6], [9, 9], [2]]
```

Также, чтобы сократить строки кода можно прибегнуть к конструкции `list comprehension`. Тогда всё уместится в одну строку, не считая импорта и объявления списка `array`:

```
from itertools import groupby

array = [4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 9, 2]
new_array = [list(grouper) for elem, grouper in groupby(array)]
# применяя такую конструкцию, мы можем обновить ссылку:
# array = [list(grouper) for elem, grouper in groupby(array)]
```

Подробнее о `list comprehension` можно почитать [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Информацию о `groupby` можно найти [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Теперь такой вопрос. Как можно преобразовать вывод в подобный вид:
Было: [[4], [2, 2], [4], [5, 5, 5], [1], [6], [9, 9], [2]]
Cтало: 4 2 2 4 5 5 5 1 6 9 9 2.
Извините, что задаю такой вопрос =)

Comment: @SilencedOne05 `for x in new_array: for y in x: print(y, end = ' ')`

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать одно и то же имя в одном и том же контексте для разных вещей (избегайте `array = groupby(array)`). Вместо этого к примеру: `nested = [list(same_items) for _, same_items in groupby(array)]`

Comment: @jfs а разница какая? Это просто обновление ссылки, а `list comprehension` я не использовал, чтобы человек не запутался и понял как работает конструкция. Но я, пожалуй, добавлю в ответ вариант с ним

Comment: @SilencedOne05 ответ обновлён

Comment: @KitScribe Я сразу и использовал `list comprehension` =)

Comment: @jfs а почему Вы считаете, что `some_data = new_represent(some_data)` - плохо? (Не считая того, что имя типа `array` плохо само по себе).

Comment: @andy.37 если вы не понимаете почему не стоит `array = groupby(array)` писать, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @jfs, [ping](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655184/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE) ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без импортов

```
array =  [4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 9, 2]
i = 0
new_array = []
while i < len(array):
    lst = [array[i]]
    while i < len(array) - 1 and array[i + 1] == array[i]:
        lst.append(array[i])
        i += 1
    new_array.append(lst)
    i += 1
print(new_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

без itertools

```
[[n]*array.count(n) for n in sorted(set(array), key=array.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda element: [element] * l.count(element), set(l)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А теперь сравните ваш результат с тем, что требуется получить. Получается разное.